# Replay chart animation with Visifire 2.6

Tags: c#, visifire

How to replay a chart animation with Visifire 2.6?

Answer (score 0):

Visifire supports animation only on initial render. As you are using Visifire 2.6, so in order to re-animate the chart you have to remove the old chart and add new chart once again. I suggest you to use the latest version of Visifire which has got lots of new features and bug fixes. Here you can re-animate the chart only by updating DataPoint's YValue.